# perform the method once in controller and don't update

Tags: php, laravel

In controller I have auto-generation of `corral_id` for Sheep model. So, when it generates all the time when I update the page. I need to generate it once at the start. How to perform this.

```
public function index():CorralResourceCollection
{
    $sheeps = Sheep::all();
    $corrals = Corral::all();

    foreach($sheeps as $sheep){
        $sheep->corral_id = $corrals->random()->id;
        $sheep->save();
    }

    return new CorralResourceCollection(Corral::with('sheeps')->paginate());
}
```

Sheep migration

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('corral_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->foreign('corral_id')->references('id')->on('corrals');
```

Comment: can you share please next code  $sheep->save();  dd($sheep->getChanges());

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ignore the corral_id while updating. Thus it will hold the previous value.

```
foreach($sheeps as $sheep){
    $sheep->corral_id = $corrals->random()->id; // ignore this line
    $sheep->save();
}
```

In case this corral_id is your primary key and you don't want to it to be auto-incremented, you can set the $incrementing to false in your Corral model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your_key_name'; // this could be id or corral_id in your case

public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: Sheep has id - primary key, name and corral_id which is foreign key, updated question with sheep migration

Comment: in that case, you don't need to update the foreign_key. Ignore updating the corral_id